# How to display user name inside product table ? API laravel 8 use eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, rest

I have 2 tables:

Table `User`:

[image: table user]

Table `Product`:

[image: table product]

And I have the model relationship:

`User` model:

```
public function product() { 
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class); 
}
```

`Product` model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'nama',
    'harga',
    'deskripsi',
    'kategori_id',
    'gambar',
];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

This is my controller:

```
class GetProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $product = Product::with(['user'])->get();

        if($product) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => 1,
                'message' => 'success get  data',
                'products' => collect($product)
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => 0,
                'message' => 'failed get data'
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my route Api :

```
Route::get('getproduct', [GetProductController::class, 'index']);
```

I want use the API for mobile app.. not Api web..

The question is: how to display only column `name` in table user inside table product?

The output I got is :

[image: the problem]

What should I change in my controller? Thanks in advance... :) I am new in laravel

Comment: One option: build query using join instead of relationships.

Comment: Please provide your code in the form of text not as images. This will make it easier to find it on google or other sides. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join approach:

```
class GetProductController extends Controller
{
public function index(){
    $product = Product::join('users', 'users.id', 'products.user_id')
                        ->select('users.name as user_name', 'products.*')->get();

        if($product){
            return response()->json([
                'success' => 1,
                'message' => 'success get  data',
                'products' => collect($product) //get() method returns a collection, no need to collect again
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => 0,
                'message' => 'failed get data'
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, you could pass a select closure into the query to just get the needed columns:

```
$product = Product::with(['user' => function($query) { 
                $query->select('id', 'name');
           ])
           ->get();
```

However, with Laravel 8, you can now [eager load the columns quicker](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns)

```
$product = Product::with(['user:id,name'])->get();
```

Pay attention to the note in the documents

> When using this feature, you should always include the id column and any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Add Product Model

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

Controller

```
 $product = Product::with(['getUser'])->get();
```

View

```
@foreach ($product as $item)
    {{ $item->getUser->name }}
@endforeach
```